# Problems installing CXF in karaf 3.0.3

Tags: cxf, apache-karaf, dosgi

I have an odd dependency problem when trying to install distributed cxf 1.6.0 on Karaf 3.0.3.

I am still on a tutorial basis when it comes to Karaf, so i have no idea what i am missing. 2 hours of googling turned up little joy.

I tried to follow install the simple greeter service from the [cxf dosgi page](http://cxf.apache.org/dosgi-apache-karaf-feature.html) but trying to install the cxf feature kind of stops me dead in my tracks.

```
$ feature:repo-add cxf-dosgi 1.6.0
$ feature:install -v cxf
...
Found installed bundle: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-features-clustering [1101]
Found installed bundle: org.apache.cxf.bundle [1102]
Error executing command: Can't install feature cxf/0.0.0:
Could not start bundle mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle-compatible/2.7.8 in feature(s) cxf-2.7.8: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.cxf.bundle [1102]: Unable to resolve 1102.0: missing requirement [1102.0] osgi.wiring.bundle; (osgi.wiring.bundle=org.springframework.beans)
```

What exactly am i missing here? I see that a spring dependency is missing, but how do i fix it. I can't seem to find that bundle anywhere, and why doens't karaf just grab it?

Comment: isn't cxf 1.6 rather old?

Comment: Yes, but it cxf-dosgi 1.6 seems to be one of the newer ones.

Answer (score 1):

Karaf is easy to use with features. 
In your case you just need to add the cxf-dosgi repo, this you have done already correctly. To use dosgi you'll need to install the correct feature.

This can be done by installing the corresponding feature.

```
feature:install -v cxf-dosgi-base
```

This will install all required features for it. In case of automatic discovery of other nodes you'll need to install the corresponding feature for it.

```
feature:list
```

will give you a list of all available features.